# NSProgressIndicator within the NSTableViewCell not update

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsprogressindicator

There is a `NSTableView` which contains several cells. There are a `NSTextField` and `NSProgressIndicator` in the cell. Each cell has its own progress indicator which represent its own uploading percentage.

Now, I need to update the progress indicator according the uploading percentage so that we could know the progress of uploading.

```
- (void)startUploading:(NSArray *)filePathArray
{
if (self.QNToken) {

    NSString *token = self.QNToken;
    NSUInteger count = [filePathArray count];

    // We may have multiple files to upload.

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i ++) {
        NSString *filePath = filePathArray[i];
        NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        NSString *key = [fileData md5String];

        // Upload option

        QNUploadOption *option = [[QNUploadOption alloc] initWithMime:nil
                                                      progressHandler:^(NSString *key, float percent) {
                                                          QNUploadDetailCell *cell = [self.tableView viewAtColumn:0 row:i makeIfNecessary:NO];
                                                          [cell.progress.animator setDoubleValue:percent];
                                                          [cell.progress displayIfNeeded];
                                                      }
                                                               params:nil
                                                             checkCrc:NO
                                                   cancellationSignal:nil];

        // Let's upload!

        [self.uploadManager putFile:filePath
                               key:key
                             token:token
                          complete: ^(QNResponseInfo *info, NSString *key, NSDictionary *resp) {
                              NSLog(@"%@", info);
                              NSLog(@"%@", resp);
                          } option:option];
    }
}
}
```

However, the progress indicator will never be animated.

I also print out the percent of the `progressHandler`: the percentage just keep increasing from 0 to 1.0

But the progress bar still keep stopping.

[image]

Any ideas?